# Show div depending to value of function in apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I develop and web app in apps script where i can select a name. Each name is in my Sheets and is depending to a profil. I can have 2 possibilities : The name have a profil or doesn't have. In the screenshot below, Sir A have a profil and Sir B and C doesn't have.

[image]

I would like to show a div in my html's page if the selected name doesn't have profil (and already hide if the selected name have a profil). So i create a function to detect if the select name have a value written in my Sheets. If it's correct, i write yes in one div (and no if it's not correct). But when i want to show div, it's doesn't work.

To try to understand my problem, i created a button to launch a function where i get the value of my result. I have undefined each time and i don't know why.

This is my html's code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
     <base target="_top">
     <?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>
     <?!= include('StyleSheet'); ?>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
   </head>
   <body>
     <form>
         <!-- NAME -->      
         <div class="form-row">
           <div class="form-group col-md-12">
             <label for="name"><b>Name :</b></label>
             <select class="form-control" id="name" onChange = "showProfil();">
               <option disabled selected>Choose ...</option>
               <?!=getNames()?>
             </select>
           </div>
         </div>
         <!-- RESULT -->
         <div><label> Result : </label><p id = "result"></p></div>

         <!-- BUTTON -->
         <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="SHOW DIV ?" id = "btnAccesQuestions" onclick = "showDivResultNo();">

         <!-- DIV DISPLAY WHEN RESULT IS NO -->
         <div id = "divResultNo">
           <h2> Result is "NO"</h2>
         </div>
     </form>
   </body>
 </html>
```

This is my server side code :

```
function doGet() {
   return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate().setTitle('Formulaire de demande de formation');  
 }

 function include(filename){
   return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
 }


 function getNames(){
   const classeur = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   const feuille = classeur.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
   var tNames = feuille.getRange("A2:A").getValues().filter(d =>d[0] !== "").flat();
   var names = deleteDuplicateValues(tNames);
   return names.map(d => "<option>" + d + "</option>").join("");
 }

 function deleteDuplicateValues(array) {
   var outArray = [];
   array.sort(lowerCase);
   function lowerCase(a,b){
     return a.toLowerCase()>b.toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1;
   }
   outArray.push(array[0]);
   for(var n in array){
     if(outArray[outArray.length-1].toLowerCase()!=array[n].toLowerCase()){
       outArray.push(array[n]);
     }
   }
   return outArray;
 }

 function getProfil(name){
   const classeur = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   const feuille = classeur.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
   var tProfils = feuille.getRange("A2:B").getValues().filter(d =>d[0] !== "");
   for (let i = 0; i < tProfils.length; i ++){
     if(tProfils[i][0] == name){
       if(tProfils[i][1] == ""){
         var resultat = "no";
       }
       else {
         var resultat = "yes";
       }
     }
   }
   return resultat;
 }

 function testProfil(){
   Logger.log(getProfil("Sir A"));
 }
```

This is my js code :

```
<script>
   function showProfil(){
     var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
     google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(profil => {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = profil;
     }).getProfil(name);
   }

   function showDivResultNo(){
     var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
     var result = document.getElementById("result").value;
     console.log(result)
     if (name != "Choose ..." && name != "" && result == "no"){
       console.log("show div after that");
     }
     else {
       console.log("div always hidden");
     }
   }

 </script>
```

And this is a screenshot of my web app after selected Sir A and press button :
[image]

If anyone can help me, it would be appreciated. You can acces to my Sheet in [this link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HR-rMPaWL23Ci8TLs2gx9uGJRNH5xIHGaRumLyXHBQk/edit?usp=sharing). Thank you for advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var result = document.getElementById("result").value;
```

#### To:

```
var result = document.getElementById("result").innerHTML;
```

- I thought that from your HTML, I thought that the reason of your issue of `I have undefined each time and i don't know why.` might be due to `.value`.

Comment: Thank you for your help Tanaike. But it doesn't work. I already write the value in the function called "showProfil", launched when i select a name. The row that you say is to get the value of the result and show div if this value is "no". But I have each time undefined

Comment: @devMethodes Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. When I tested my proposed modification using your provided Spreadsheet, when the one of options in select box is selected and the button is clicked, the value of `result` can be seen in the console. So I cannot replicate your situation.`But I have each time undefined`. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. In order to correctly replicate your current issue, can you provide your current script? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @devMethodes By the way, in your situation, when you modify your script, please reflect your latest script to the Web Apps. When the latest script is not reflected, `undefined` is returned. Please be careful about this. I'm worried about this.

Comment: Don't apologize Tanaike, you help me :) If you want, i give the link of my Sheets and can acces to my current script. If you don't want, and i can understand, all of my script (except CSS) is in my post. And this is my latest scripts to the Web Apps, i work in developper's mode.

Comment: @devMethodes Thank you for replying. When I tested your current provided Spreadsheet including my modification, when the latest script is reflected in the Web Apps, I can confirm that the value can be seen from `var result = document.getElementById("result").innerHTML;`. Could you please confirm it again?

Comment: Sorry, you have wright, i tried with Sir A and not others. It's work !!!!!

Comment: @devMethodes Thank you for replying and testing it again. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.